# How can I tell if I've already 'liked' a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I go to some Facebook pages, and I can't find a 'like' link and I'm not sure if I had hit it before or not.  Is there an easy way to tell if I've 'liked' something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There'll be a small "Unlike" link on the left hand side under the "n people like this" box:

[image]
<sub>(source: [free-online.co.uk](http://www.forman.free-online.co.uk/images/already-liked.png))</sub>

Comment: One could also go on the lack of a "Like" button next to the Page's name.

Comment: @Voyag, yeh, but some pages don't have 'like' buttons and I not always sure a page will have one.